# How to get the main color of an image?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to find the dominant color of an image. But not the most present pixel. Indeed, let us imagine that there are many Greens, I would like them to get together', rather than form a competition'.
If I do a simple average, I end up with values that don't match the visible colors that much, but more with a light brown that mixes everything together.

I do everything under python with PIL, but I am also interested in a general "technique" (without language).

Do you have any leads?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is a 'color' then? And what is 'dominant color'?

Comment: I've tried to do a mean color, and a basic "more present pixel". The main color is the color mainly visible on the image.  In other words, the color you would see if you put yourself far enough away from the image.  It "summarizes" the image.

Comment: Can you give example of an image and main color of that image?

Comment: This is an exemple: [image](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/13/2/1553613907-screenshot-from-2019-03-26-16-24-21.png)